# Migrating a IMAP mailbox into local folder structure in Thunderbird or Live Mail

Tags: windows, thunderbird, imap, pop3, email

I have a big IMAP Mailbox with a great number of folders. I would like to transfer the folder structure in to a local structure in either Thunderbird or Windows Live Mail, and switch the mailbox to POP3.

How would I go about this? Is there a function in Thunderbird that allows me to do this? Alternatively, is there a tool to dump a IMAP box into some file format that can be interpreted/imported by Thunderbird or Live Mail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try dragging and dropping the actual folders onto the "Local Folders" folder in Thunderbird. It worked for me IME.